# Getting error while querying custom created "Knowledge exploration service"

Tags: machine-learning, azure-cognitive-services

I have created a custom demo based on documentation. When I host my files locally it is giving the following error "CancellationToken. Timeout!" and I'm not getting any search suggestions from web service. What could be the issue?

I tried my best to mimic the grammar file given in sample example

**Search.schema**

```
{
    "attributes":[
        {"name":"ClassCD","type":"string"},
        {"name":"Year","type":"string"},
        {"name":"Keyword", "type":"String", "synonyms":"Keyword.syn"}
    ]
}
```

**Keyword.syn**

```
["class","grade"]
["year","academicyear"]
["year","schoolyear"]
```

**Search.Data**

```
{"ClassCD":"class 1","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 2","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 3","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 4","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 5","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 6","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 7","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 8","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 9","Year":2018}
{"ClassCD":"class 10","Year":2018}
```

**Grammar File**

```
<grammar root="GetStudents">
    <import schema="search.schema" name="search" />

    <!-- Get Students by Class-->
    <rule id="GetStudents">
        <example>students from class 1</example>

        students  

        <tag>
          yearOnce = false;
          isBeyondEndOfQuery = false;
          searchQuery = All();
        </tag>

        <item repeat="1-">
            <tag>AssertEquals(isBeyondEndOfQuery, false);</tag>

            <one-of>
                <item>
                    from <attrref uri="search#ClassCD" name="className"/>
                    <tag>searchQuery=className;</tag>   
                </item>

                <tag> searchQuery=searchQuery;</tag>
            </one-of>
        </item>

        <tag> out=searchQuery; </tag>
    </rule>

</grammar>
```

Comment: Can you show the code?